# Easy way to Sync Data between MongoDB and Apache Solr

Tags: java, mongodb, solr

I recently started working with MongoDB and Apache Solr. I am using MongoDB as a data store and I want Apache Solr to create index for my data for the search feature in my application.

After some research I found out, there are basically 2 methods to sync the data between MongoDB and Solr.

1) using Solr DataImportHandler -

For this I used SolrMongoImporter created by james and followed his tutorial on [github](https://github.com/james75/SolrMongoImporter)

I was able to successfully run the Import Handler and Solr identified the ImportHandler but it was not importing any documents into solr. Every time it said updated documents=0.

2) Then I tried switching to MongoDB side, to look if anything exists there and I found 
[MongoDBConnector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) provided by 10gen.

When I followed the instructions, and ran the connector, it is trying to post lot of documents to Solr and it gives the following output.

```
2012-11-24 15:15:20,665 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.010 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:21,674 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.009 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:22,683 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.008 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:23,694 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.010 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:24,702 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.008 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:25,711 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.008 seconds.
2012-11-24 15:15:26,722 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (POST) with body '<commit />' in 0.010 seconds.
```

But no data is there in Solr.

I wanted to know which approach worked for you guys, and is there any good tutorial on MongoDB and Solr Integration.

Also, I am looking for a real-time sync between MongoDB and solr, i.e. as soon as any product is added to my mongodb, I want it updated in solr index and reflect in search results.

I am using MongoDB 2.0.4 and Solr 3.6.1.

Comment: Even if it is not java, you might find some inspiration in this [link](http://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-and-solr.html).

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop is an option for creating SOLR indexes. I haven't done this first hand, but have heard from people [such as etsy](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/solr-lucene-and-hadoop-etsy-12985268) who are.

On [this course](http://www.lucenerevolution.org/training) at lucene revolution they talked about using hadoop to update the indexes in some SOLR cores. Unfortunately I don't think the course material is publicly available.

And at [this talk](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodb-uk-2012/humongous) the speaker talked about the mongo/hadoop support.

Other related links:

- [Indexing Files via Solr and Java MapReduce](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/indexing-files-via-solr-and-java-mapreduce/)
- [Using Hadoop to Create Solr Indexes](http://www.likethecolor.com/2010/09/26/using-hadoop-to-create-solr-indexes/)
- [Mongo-Hadoop Connector](http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB%2BHadoop+Connector.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the replica set mode? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/

In the beginning, I was getting the same output as you described although there were no data in Solr. After, I set up replication mode, it seems that oplog file was created and mongodbconnector was correctly synchronizing with SOLR. Works quite nicely for me.

Comment: it will be helpful, if you explain how to configure replication mode to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using mongoConnector. Check out http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector